# How can we remove browser saved password suggestion with material ui textfield

Tags: css, reactjs, browser, material-ui

"How can we remove this type of browser suggestion in Textfield inside form tag. User must need to type password without selecting from suggestion"

[image: showing suggestion on focus]

"Tried to add textfield autocomplete="off

```
 <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          color="secondary"
          fullWidth
          classes={{
            root: classes.textfieldRoot,
          }}
          type="password"
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          autoFocus
          autoComplete="off"
          inputProps={{
            autoComplete: "new-password",
            form: {
              autoComplete: "off",
            },
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers don't let you disable autocompletion. See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete.

There are some hacky ways to do it if you really need to (which I wouldn't recommend), like changing the input "type" to text and using JS to capture keystrokes and replace them with '*' characters or something, but there isn't a supported native way of doing it.